# Would this theoretical battery be practical: 2 charged objects close to one another?

Tags: electrostatics, batteries, coulombs-law, electrical-engineering, energy-storage

Consider a system which stores energy by forcing two charged objects (of the same charge) close to one another. When the energy needs to be used, a latch could open and the objects would accelerate away from each other, powering some machine. It’s a really simple idea. Why isn’t something like that used?

Comment: Sounds like a capacitor.  And they are used in some cases for energy storage.

Comment: Whether something is practical is engineering, not so much physics.  Probably a better fit for [electronics.se].

Answer (score 3):

Charged objects slowly lose their charge via *leakage*. this is particularly problematic when the potential difference between the objects is large (more than ~hundreds of volts), which it would need to be in order to develop a measurable amount of repulsive force between them. In comparison, a simple compression spring squeezed between those objects will store its "charge" indefinitely; there are no leakage mechanisms present to make the spring relax over time. Compared to a simple spring, the electrostatic method of storing mechanical work is quite impractical.

However... There is one very important application of your idea: nuclear fission. when a uranium nucleus splits, it suddenly becomes two nuclei with the same charge sign so close they are almost touching, and the electrostatic repulsion between them is tremendous- which accelerates the fission fragments to extremely high velocities, imparting to them very large kinetic energies- which, when multiplied in a chain reaction, gives you a tremendously powerful explosion.

Richard Serber's book *The Los Alamos Primer* explains this mechanism in good detail.

Comment: How does that Coloumb repulsion compare in magnitude to the energy level difference between the original U nucleus $-->$ two daughter nuclei?

Comment: Serber's book explains that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the spring will slowly relax by creep deformation of the material, though that generally doesn't mattter practically.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of energy stored would be very small, and you'd also induce charges on any nearby conducting objects.